# Duda con funciones metodos SOAP

Tags: php, soap

como lo interpretan esto?
utilice este código

```
$url="miurlwsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url,array("trace" => 1));
           $f=$client->__getFunctions();
           var_dump($f[0]);
```

y me arroja esto

string(101) "AutentificaIniResponse AutentificaIni(AutentificaIni $parameters)"

Ahora estoy tratando de consumir ese ws con esto y no muestra nada

```
$url="miurl.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url,array("trace" => 1));
$para=Array('paraA'=>'12345678','paraB'=>'33333');
$result=$client->AutentificaIni($para);
print_r($result);
```

y lo unico que me muestra es: AutentificaIni

Sin embargo en SOAPUI me muestra los valores sin problemas.

Faltara algo mas?

Comment: En la documentación de [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.soap.php) no aparece nada de `AutentificaIni`. Es mas, he buscado en San Google y... ¡solo aparece esta página como resultado!

Comment: Es que ese AutentificaIni es un método propio de ese servicio servicio SOAP al cual deseo acceder, no es que sea una función de SOAP PHP

Comment: Me di cuenta después de dejar este comentario. Mira mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El método [`__getFunctions`](http://php.net/manual/es/soapclient.getfunctions.php) de `SoapClient` no devuelve las funciones o métodos de la propia clase `SoapClient`, sino la lista de funciones disponibles que ofrece el servicio web de acuerdo con el archivo WSDL.

La forma de ejecutar dichas funciones es a través del método [`__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/es/soapclient.soapcall.php), que en su versión mas básica tiene esta forma:

```
mixed SoapClient::__soapCall(string $function_name, array $arguments);
```

`$function_name` se correspondería con `"AutentificaIni"` en tu caso, y `$arguments` con `$para`:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall("AutentificaIni", $para);
```

Comment: En mi experiencia también puedes invocarlos así: `$client->metodo($params)`, se que es menos dinámico que `__soapCall` pero a esa función le he encontrado bugs reportados: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73383